# How to find the symbol table in a TI DSP. (TMS320C5510)

Tags: debugging-symbols

That's it, just want to know how to find the symbol table in a binary I pulled from a DSP chip.  I know it could be stripped, just don't know how to tell.

Comment: I don't know about that specific DSP, but it's fairly common to compress binaries with a loader stub in devices - did you try to run binwalk over it?

Comment: Did you check the manufacturer's documentation ?! (http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru423i/spru423i.pdf)